# openHAB rules: Is there an IDE that gives compile-time errors for openHAB rules?

Tags: compiler-errors, openhab

I use Visual Code, when I save the files they are compiled in the running openHAB instance, and if I'm logged in and do log:tail I see the errors. I would prefer having errors appear in an IDE. Is that currently possibly with any IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you haven't installed the openHAB extension or you haven't configured it properly. See [the configuration instructions for the VSCode openHAB extension](https://github.com/openhab/openhab-vscode/blob/master/README.md#configuration) for details. The important thing is that the extension connects to a running instance of openHAB to check your code as you type. The extension literally uses the same parser that OH uses to load and parse the files so you will see all the same errors and get better code completion when the extension connects to a running OH instance. Make sure you have the openHAB:host parameter properly set and port 5007 on the openHAB host is accessible by the machine running VSCode.

Comment: My intended question was whether its possible to get compile errors in the GUI, and according to Richard in this thread, the answer is no. There is no IDE doing the syntax/semantic/type checking of a compiler like running the script does: https://community.openhab.org/t/is-there-an-ide-that-gives-compile-time-errors-for-openhab-rules/80951